# Why is my response.redirect() not working properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.redirect

Two aspx pages are involved with the problem. in one form I am collecting the entity and binding it in a session variable and then with button clicked, I am trying to get to the other aspx page with response.redirect("") method. But, the problem is its gives me an error message with a strange URl.

let me show you the code I have writen

```
 formSaleMoneyReceiptEntity = ViewFormSaleMoneyReceipt_DAO.GetMoneyReceiptByFormSL(formSl);
            Session["MoneyReceipt"] = formSaleMoneyReceiptEntity;
            Response.Redirect("~/Reports/MoneyRepeiptFormReport.aspx",false);
```

I am using local host and the URl I am getting is that

http://www.google-feed.net/results.php?q=localhost 5808 StudentManagement FormSaleMoneyReceipt aspx &cx=002904446094441487865%3Ate-nlsbrcdy&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=UTF-8&said=&do=search&empty=0&from=2&CID=1

why is this so? I don't have any idea. Please help me out.

Comment: try `~/MoneyRepeiptFormReport.aspx`

Comment: could it be because you misspelled Receipt in MoneyRepeiptFormReport?

Comment: I read this about 20 times to try to spot the bug, and missed the spelling error every time. D'oh!

Comment: Thnx, for your quick response, It was a typo error in my code, now its working pecfectly after correcting the typed error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the URL that is passed to the browser doesn't exist, so you're getting a redirect to a Google search page instead.

Is it `~/Reports/MoneyReceiptFormReport.aspx` by any chance?

A good tool to use to debug this kind of situation is [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). This sits as a proxy between your Web server and your browser and issues a trace of what requests and responses are made. Browsers have a habit of reformatting error messages, Fiddler will show you exactly what's sent to the server and what comes back.